# How to convert a certificate in .pfx format to .jks in HP-UX server

Tags: openssl, ssl, conversion, certificates, hp-ux

I have a task to convert a .pfx SSL certificate to .jks format in a HP-UX B.11.31 server to be configured in our application's server.xml file, (keystoreFile=) for our 8090 connector port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714112/2908599) you can use command like:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mypfxfile.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore clientcert.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

You will need java 1.6 or higher version

Comment: thank you this worked! Romeo Ninov